# C# any pattern matching with database string

Tags: c#, string, pattern-matching

I need help in the task of finding text pattern in a database. 
I developed a program in C#. I need to search for a text pattern, input by the user, which will be searched in the database. The problem consists in the fact that user input doesn't need to match the string in the database, but simply be similar to it. The example below illustrates this:

e.g. database string is "I need to find text in database"

and user input is "find database need"

I hope you understand.
Please, help me to find any pattern in database string.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying have string in C# from a DB and want to search them or that you want to query a DB from c# and return string records that match the pattern?

Comment: finding user string in database

Comment: Your  question is not very well explained , if you want to query the database? why don't you use like operator?

Comment: How about using the available [full text search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)?

Comment: Have you read about wildcard search? What type of database are you using: SQL, MySQL, Access? What have you done so far?

Comment: Simple, but not very fast approach: [split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms228388.aspx) user input (by space?) and perform `LIKE` search with each element. - `... WHERE [Field] LIKE '%find%' AND [Field] LIKE '%database%' AND [Field] LIKE '%need%'`.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: ya this can be possible

Comment: but how can I create procedure with variable number of parameters

Answer (score 1):

Method to generate statement:

```
    public static string WildFindStatement( String search )
    {
        //REPLACE THE STRING WITH SQL INJECTION SAFE PARAMTERS
        //THATS ONLY FOR CONCEPT SHOWING (or at least a string buildeR)

        string sql = "select * from bla where 1=1 ";

        string  [] sa = search.Split(  new char[] {' '} );
        foreach ( var s in sa )
        {
            sql += ( " AND columBla LIKE '%" + s + "%'");
        }
        return sql;
    }
```

Call :

```
string s = WildFindStatement( "the wookies you must find" );
```

Result :

```
select * from bla where 1=1  
    AND columBla LIKE '%the%' 
    AND columBla LIKE '%wookies%' 
    AND columBla LIKE '%you%' 
    AND columBla LIKE '%must%' 
    AND columBla LIKE '%find%'
```

Comment: but it returns duplicate entries

Comment: just find your statement in 'this all the you cookies wookies must you find'

Comment: sure.if you have "the wookies you must find" in the database AND "all the wookies you must find" you will get TWO rows. you may add TOP 1 if you only want the first.